# Alternating row-column headers in worksheet with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to print output from a custom structure into Excel file. What I am trying to do is:

COLUMN NAME

PLAYER

PLAYER

COLUMN NAME

PLAYER

PLAYER

But What I am getting is

COLUMN NAME

COLUMN NAME

PLAYER

PLAYER

CODE:

```
int i = 1;

foreach (var item in scoresheet.Positions)
{
    var column = wb.Cells;

    if ((i % 5) == 1)
    {
        column["A" + i].LoadFromText("Initial Rank");
    }
    else
    {
        column["A" + i + 1].LoadFromText(item.Player.FirstName);
    }
    i++;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your line:

```
column["A" + i + 1].LoadFromText(item.Player.FirstName);
```

I assume you want that to be, say, a result of "A2" when i is equal to 1.  BUT, what you will actually end up with is "A11" since it will do it as a string concatenation.  What you need is:

```
column["A" + (i + 1)].LoadFromText(item.Player.FirstName);
```

Comment: Yes, I figured this out few minutes after posting this question.